# How to create a static header, cart, and search bar

Tags: css, css-position, static-html

I am trying to create a static header that keeps my search bar, mini cart, and header picture fixed at the top while scrolling.

Where can I locate the CSS/HTML properties to edit this?

The website is nkdscty.com for reference.

Thank you

Comment: You might consider using a CSS framework like Bootstrap or Foundation rather than trying to write and browser-test all that from scratch.

Comment: Google "sticky header"

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Use the css `position:fixed` rule. Use `top:0` to fix it to the top.

```
header{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
```

Comment: When I place the rules on the appropriate headers the layout changes.  What property will keep the header intact?

Thank you

Comment: Nothing will fix something other than the fixed position.